# email.header.decode_headers() throws an HeaderParseError

Tags: python, email, email-headers

I'm trying to decode email Subject headers.

I'm doing this (the regex is for adding a space between the two = 's:

```
header = '=?iso-8859-1?B?TU9UT1IubmwgbmlldXdzYnJpZWYgPiBOaWV1d2UgdmVya29vcHRvcHBl?==?iso-8859-1?B?ciBTdXp1a2kg?='
header = re.sub(r"(==)(?!$)", u"\0= =", header)
email.header.decode_header(header)
```

But that throws an HeaderParseError:

```
HeaderParseError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/leon/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.7/email/header.pyc in decode_header(header)
    106                         # now we throw the lower level exception away but
    107                         # when/if we get exception chaining, we'll preserve it.
--> 108                         raise HeaderParseError
    109                 if dec is None:
    110                     dec = encoded
```

The funny thing is, if I copy the output of the re.sub() to my clipboard and do:

```
email.header.decode_header('=?iso-8859-1?B?TU9UT1IubmwgbmlldXdzYnJpZWYgPiBOaWV1d2UgdmVya29vcHRvcHBl?= =?iso-8859-1?B?ciBTdXp1a2kg?=')
```

it works!

So I guess something's wrong with the encoding of re.sub() but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The header is [invalid to begin with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384006/email-header-decode-headers-throws-an-headerparseerror/7384038#7384038). Does this happen for all e-mails you're trying to parse, or just some? How does the actual raw header portion look? Perhaps a newline (between the tokens) gets lost when you're reading the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack a space between the RFC2047 tokens in the example which doesn't work. Your attempt to repair it is, however, also incorrect; you should be replacing with `u"= ="`, not `u"\0= ="`.

It would be much better if you could find the source of such errors and correct it, rather than attempt to fix it up afterwards based on, at best, good guesses about what your data ought to be.

Comment: This workaround is already present in the question. :) The question is, why does it happen?

Comment: The `\0` in the ostensible workaround is incorrect. Will update my reply.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I found the regex somewhere and I thought the \0 was for a group reference or something.